# Special characters cannot be identified by Reg Ex

Tags: regex

I have this Reg Ex

```
\b\d{7}PM\w{2}\d*\b
```

so based on the reg ex it should only accept
 7 Numbers + PM + 2 alphanumeric + Any Length of Number. so this will accepts such as this respectively as it has \b in the beginning and in the end

```
1032213PM39849723
```

My question is that why does the regex above accepts

```
1032213PM39849723<\test>
```

or

```
1032213PM39849723.
```

or

```
>1032213PM39849723
```

and not

```
A1032213PM39849723
```

or

```
1032213PM39849723K
```

it really bugs me why is this happening, if there are any changes to be made in the regex so that any other characters would not be accepted at the end or the beginning please tell me so.

Comment: You're confusing [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and [start/end of string anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the flavour of regex function you use, but typically that regex does not mean that *the entire string has to consist of this and only this*, it merely means that *some part of the string has to match this*. If you want to match the whole string, add start and end anchors:

```
^\d{7}PM\w{2}\d*$
```

Comment: What deceze said. :) +1

Comment: well why does A1032213PM39849723 is not accepted? some part of that string is also follows the regex (after the A)

Comment: @User Well, look up what `\b` means exactly: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: @deceze i think i already get it but i just want to clarify.. \b only works for WORDS meaning to say the characters that either on the beginning or the end is should be \w (alpha numeric) and because < is not an alphanumeric word making it valid when using \b.. am i right?

Comment: @User Basically, yes. There is a *word boundary* in ">1", but not in "A1". "A1" is a continuing "word".